# Sorting an array with weights in another array

Tags: php

I get two arrays from

```
$check = getmxrr ( $domain, $mxhosts, $weight );
```

I want to get the mxhosts in a third array from lowest to highest weight.

For simplicity let's have simple array names and values:

```
$s = array('slowest','fast','very slow', 'slow','very fast', 'fastest');
$n = array( 40,       10,    30,          20,    5,           0       );
```

Now, with this code, I can get the ordered array I'm looking for:

```
$o = array_combine($n, $s);
ksort($o);
```

But, if there are elements with the same weight, only the last element with the repeated weight would appear in the ordered array.

Is there any similar (low footprint) solution without this issue?

Illustrative cases follow.

*Weight values are unique. Output is OK*:

> ```
> [0] => fastest
> [5] => very fast
> [10] => fast
> [20] => slow
> [30] => very slow
> [40] => slowest
> ```

*We have same-weight elements. Output is NOT OK (fast is gone)*:

```
$n = array( 40,       10,    30,         10,       20,    5,           0       );
$s = array('slowest','fast','very slow','fast2', 'slow','very fast', 'fastest');
```

> ```
> [0] => fastest
> [5] => very fast
> [10] => fast2
> [20] => slow
> [30] => very slow
> [40] => slowest
> ```

Comment: share code for array_combine method

Comment: it makes a new array $o with keys from $s and value from $n by order $o[$n[0]] = $s[0]

Comment: @CoDeaDDict it's a native function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: I'm trying to understand if two elements has the same weight ksort won't sort the array by the keys correctly? Can you show how it sorts it?

Comment: and how would you like the array as well ;-), maybe natsort() would do the trick ... depends on what you want exactly ...

Comment: @Guy will add output to the question.

Comment: @yenta yes they are host names from MX Records and I do believe they are unique.

Comment: Your problem is that keys are unique, therefore the one key goes away, you'll have to switch the keys and values ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you believe the host names are unique, switch the order of the combine

```
$n = array( 40,       10,    30,         10,       20,    5,           0       );
$s = array('slowest','fast','very slow','fast2', 'slow','very fast', 'fastest');
$o = array_combine($s, $n);
```

and use asort to sort on values while maintaining keys

```
asort($o);
```

than your sorted host names are in array_keys

```
var_dump(array_keys($o));
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "fastest"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "very fast"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "fast2"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "fast"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "slow"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "very slow"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "slowest"
}

var_dump($o);
array(7) {
  ["fastest"]=>
  int(0)
  ["very fast"]=>
  int(5)
  ["fast2"]=>
  int(10)
  ["fast"]=>
  int(10)
  ["slow"]=>
  int(20)
  ["very slow"]=>
  int(30)
  ["slowest"]=>
  int(40)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$s = array('slowest','fast', 'slow', 'fastest', 'slow 2');
$n = array( 40, 10, 20, 0, 20);

$res = array();
foreach ($n as $k => $v) {
    $res[$v] .= count($res[$v]) ? ",{$s[$k]}" : $s[$k];
}

ksort($res);
$res = explode(',', implode(',', $res));

print_r($res);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => fastest
    [1] => fast
    [2] => slow
    [3] => slow 2
    [4] => slowest
)
*/
```

Comment: The value of wights are not important; only they need to be in the correct order. So, all I want in the above case is `('fastest', 'fast', 'slow', 'slow 2', 'slowest')`

Comment: Thank you for the effort. This code does get the job done, but generates many notices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a > $b)
        return 1;
    elseif ($b > $a)
        return -1;
    else
       return 0;
}

uksort($array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: Is `$array` in the above, the `$weight` array? If so, what effect would that have on `$mxhosts` array? -- `$mxhosts` is what I need sorted *as per values in `$weight`* though